# NSURL not convert safe string

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I want to send url with get parameters:

```
let customAllowedSet =  NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"=\"#%/<>?@\\^`{|}&").invertedSet

guard let safeUrl = "\(GVariables.Url)?id=\(self.UUID)&device_name=\(UIDevice.currentDevice().name)&email=\(email)&first_name=\(firstName)&last_name=\(lastName)".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(customAllowedSet) else {
       return
     }
     print(safeUrl)
     guard let url = NSURL(string: safeUrl) else {
          return
     }
     print(url)
```

Output is:

> http:%2F%2Fmyurl.com:8000%2Fs%2F%3Fid%3D15FDA6B3-C51A-4057-8F98-0143981CC5C8%26device_name%3DArtem's
>   iPhone%26email%3D%26first_name%3D%26last_name%3D

But converting to NSURL always return `nil`.

Comment: It probably means your `customAllowedSet` is faulty. How is it implemented?

Comment: sorry, added ```customAllowedSet```

Comment: oh, thanks. It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom character set you're using to encode your URL may look efficient but it is incomplete.

In your case, for example, it lacked encoding the space character " ".

It's better to use a known method instead:

```
yourStringURL.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet())
```